# IPPROTO_TCP or SOL_SOCKET

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, boost-asio, tcp-keepalive

I have a simple P2P connection between my peers on a TCP socket. My client and server both are running on *Linux*. I have turned on [TCP keep_alive functionality](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/) on my TCP sockets on both sides. I am using [boost::asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to connect, read ane write data on my tcp sockets on both sides.

The **tcp keep_alive** expamples use `IPPROTO_TCP` and `SOL_SOCKET` which is confusing. Following are properties I set on my socket. But I am confused whether to use `IPPROTO_TCP` or `SOL_SOCKET` because both of them compile well on both the platforms.

**Code:**

```
int on = 1;
setsockopt(socketNativeHandle, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &on, sizeof(int)
int timeOut = 3; //seconds
setsockopt(socketNativeHandle, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &timeOut, sizeof(int)
setsockopt(socketNativeHandle, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &timeOut, sizeof(int))
int unackCount = 1;
setsockopt(socketNativeHandle, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &unackCount, sizeof(int))
```

OR

```
int on = 1;
setsockopt(socketNativeHandle, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_NODELAY, &on, sizeof(int)
int timeOut = 3; //seconds
setsockopt(socketNativeHandle, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &timeOut, sizeof(int)
setsockopt(socketNativeHandle, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &timeOut, sizeof(int))
int unackCount = 1;
setsockopt(socketNativeHandle, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_KEEPCNT, &unackCount, sizeof(int))
```

**Question:**
Should I use `SOL_SOCKET` on both sides or should I use `IPPROTO_TCP` on both sides? Is there a way to decide this at runtime? Note that I have very simple peer to peer wifi connection.

Comment: Successful compilation is necessary but not sufficient to prove correctness. Which of them actually works? You *certainly* don't need a way to decide this at runtime.

Comment: `IPPROTO_TCP` seems to work for the numbers based properties like `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL` and `TCP_KEEPCNT`. Looks like the boolean based on/off properties are set `SOL_SOCKET` level. Slowly getting to understand this better.

Comment: I suggest `SOL_SOCKET` for the `SO_*` options and `IPPROTO_TCP` for the `TCP_*` options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOL is abbreviation of socket_level, which designed for `SO_*` options, such as `SO_REUSEPORT`

`IPPROTO_*` is designed for options of a specific network protocol, such as IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_TCP

More:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Socket_002dLevel-Options.html#Socket_002dLevel-Options
- https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Network-Sockets-and-Communication.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockopt
- https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp

Answer (score 1):

here a IBM doc says:

> level
> is the protocol level for which the socket option is being set. `SOL_SOCKET` and `IPPROTO_TCP` are supported.
> All optname values beginning with “SO_” are for protocol level `SOL_SOCKET` and are interpreted by the general socket code.
> All optname values beginning with “TCP_” are for protocol level `IPPROTO_TCP` and are interpreted by the TCP/IP internal code.

but I'm not sure if it applies to linux too.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zvm/7.1?topic=functions-setsockopt

---

TCP_* options

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html#:~:text=set%20to-,IPPROTO_TCP

SO_* options

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html#:~:text=level%20set%20to-,SOL_SOCKET

NOTE: use chrome can scroll to highlight keyword in man page.

---

here also a `SOL_TCP`, seems same as IPPROTO_TCP

```bash
$ ag 'SOL_SOCKET|SOL_TCP|IPPROTO_TCP' -R /usr/include/ --file-search-regex .h
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h
206:# define SOL_TCP        6   /* TCP level */

/usr/include/netinet/in.h
50:    IPPROTO_TCP = 6,    /* Transmission Control Protocol.  */
51:#define IPPROTO_TCP      IPPROTO_TCP

/usr/include/linux/in.h
37:  IPPROTO_TCP = 6,       /* Transmission Control Protocol    */
38:#define IPPROTO_TCP      IPPROTO_TCP


/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h
9:#define SOL_SOCKET    1

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket-constants.h
25:#define SOL_SOCKET 1
```